# unable to use client.channels.cache.get(")

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to find the guild, then channel in said guild using the follow code.

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.find(guild => guild.name === "bla bla bla");
const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'bla bla bla.2');
```

```
client.once('ready', () => { 
   console.log('Bot is ready!') 
});

client.login(token)
```

I check to see if the channel is found or not, however I end up getting an error of  `guild is undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to cache a channel for some reason, To do that here is my solution (*Used the `ready` event*):

```
client.on('ready', ()=>{
   client.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL_ID);
})
```

For the case of `guild is undefined`, Could be caused by not finding the guild so you should check if the bot is in the server that you're looking for by name and also be sure that the name is as typed!

Comment: That's how you get a channel *from* cache

Comment: nvm, the real problem is that I was using 
client.login(realtoken).then(() => {
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('757709920274743336');
    if (channel) {
        console.log("good morning")
        channel.send("Good Morning")
    } else {
        if (!channel) {
            console.log('Pois é, esse canal não foi encontrado...')
        }
    }
})