# client.channels.cache.get(<id>) showing unidenfied in discord.js i already tried many solution

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
require('dotenv').config();

const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
const channel = client.channels.cache.get("967808235048423484");

client.on('ready',() => {
  console.log(`${client.user.tag}  logged in`);
console.log(channel);
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORDJS_BOT_TOKEN);
```

output:-

```
Anonymous HELPER  #4205  logged in 
undefined
```

I already check other solution

1. https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-set-both-status-and-activity-in-one-go
2. [Discord.js : TypeError: client.channels.get is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60699620/discord-js-typeerror-client-channels-get-is-not-a-function)
3. [client.channels.cache.get('id') returns empty Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69770328/client-channels-cache-getid-returns-empty-map)
4. [Send a message with Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45120618/send-a-message-with-discord-js)
5. [unable to use client.channels.cache.get(")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67729697/unable-to-use-client-channels-cache-get)

like

```
const channel = await client.channels.fetch(CHANNEL_ID) 
error:-SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
const channel = client.channels.fetch(channelID)
```

version -

```
"discord.js": "^13.6.0",
"dotenv": "^16.0.0"
"node.js": "^16.14.2"
```

Comment: i have not used name method yet

Comment: I read the discord.js documentation but I cant understand `emit method`

Comment: i got the answer

Answer (score 0):

The client is not ready at the time, so the cache is empty. Put that in the `ready` event.

```js
client.on('ready',() => {
  const channel = client.channels.cache.get("967808235048423484");
  console.log(`${client.user.tag}  logged in`);
  console.log(channel);
});
```

Comment: still undefined ?

Comment: Check that the bot has permissions to see the channel and the ID is valid

Comment: ID is valid but is bot need any specific permissions

Comment: client.channels.fetch('967808235048423484')
    .then(channel => console.log(channel.name))
    .catch(console.error);
error:-
    DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel

Comment: @HoneyHoney that means the channel ID is invalid

Comment: is there some type of permission to be given to use channel id